# Swagger same path specified twice

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Is it possible to have same path appear more than once in one API spec which is being rendered by Swagger-UI?

Should I create separate api specs and load two instances of Swagger-UI? What is the best way to handle this?

For ex. I have endpoint called /oauth/token which I want to document with one set of parameters for OAuth Authorization Code flow and the same endpoint /oauth/token documents for client_credentials flow with different set of parameters.

```
/oauth/token:
    post:
      summary: token endpoint for authorization_code flow
      parameters:
        - name: code
          type: string
          description: Required for Authorization Code Flow
          in: formData
          required: true
        - name: grant_type
          type: string
          description: Grant Type should be specified as authorization_code
          in: formData
          required: true
          default: authorization_code
          enum:
          - authorization_code
          - client_credentials
        - name: client_id
          type: string
          description: Consumer Key
          in: formData
          required: true
        - name: client_secret
          type: string
          description: Consumer Secret
          in: formData
          required: true
        - name: endOtherSessions
          in: formData
          type: boolean
          required: false
          default: false
          description: Optional parameter. Default is false - do not allow concurrent login. Send true to end any other user sessions.
      tags:
        - OAuth2 Authorization Code
```

Same endpoint for client_credentials flow

```
/oauth/token2:
     post:
       summary: token for client credentials
       parameters:
         - name: grant_type
           type: string
           description: Grant Type should be specified as client_credentials
           in: formData
           required: true
           default: client_credentials
           enum:
          - authorization_code
          - client_credentials
         - name: client_id
           type: string
           description: Consumer Key
           in: formData
           required: true
         - name: client_secret
           type: string
           description: Consumer Secret
           in: formData
           required: true
       tags:
         - OAuth2 Client Credentials
```

Comment: Are you asking for the OAuth2 endpoints only? Because if so, you don't need to specify those at all. OAuth2 security is described differently with Swagger.

Comment: Its for both oauth2 and regular resource end points. Oauth2 was the first time where I have come across the need to have same path repeated.

Comment: Can you give an example for non-oauth2 paths? Because it's really not relevant for it. I can give you the specific solution for oauth2, but would rather see the actual issue you have.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I don't have specific issue with non oauth as of now. Can you please help for oauth2 specific scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is about OAuth2 rather than a single endpoint with different parameters, then the solution is actually different.

Swagger has a specific way to document authorization methods, including the 4 common OAuth2 flows.

These are described using the [Security Definitions Object](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securityDefinitionsObject) which is located at the top [Swagger object](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#swaggerSecurityDefinitions).

Within it, you can define one or more OAuth2 flows. The spec itself provides a sample for the `implicit` flow, but others follow a similar structure. The difference is by which fields are provided, namely `authorizationUrl` and `tokenUrl` (depending on the flow type).

Once you have that, you can specify which security schemes are required. You can specify it for all the operations at the [Swagger object](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#swaggerSecurity) or at the [Operation level](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#operationSecurity).

The spec allows you to define that a set of security methods are required together, or that the user can choose between given sets.

Comment: Thanks Ron. This helps to document the api spec but there is no good way to show OAuth2 security definitions documentation from Swagger-UI hence I was trying to duplicate the swagger path and document similar to https://api.gettyimages.com/swagger/ui/index.html#!/OAuth (this is swagger ver 1.2)

Comment: Looks like the OAuth section is done as HTML not using Swagger-UI.

Comment: Well, you can't do that. There's a feature request for swagger-ui to show the available securities, can't say if/when it would be implemented. What Getty Images are doing there is out of scope of the spec is not officially supported by Swagger.